# How do I ssh to a machine with dynamic ip after the IP has changed due to reboot?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I was working remotely on a Ubuntu workstation on a private network with dynamic IP, which I was reaching by connecting to a gateway machine with assigned a static IP. Then I had to remotely reboot the workstation, and I can't connect to it anymore. I think that's because the machine has been assigned another dynamic IP.

How do I figure out the new IP assigned to the workstation after reboot, so that I can continue working on it, without physically accessing said machine?

I tried nmap (as detailed e.g. [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/423709/how-to-see-all-devices-on-your-network-with-nmap-on-linux/)) but the workstation isn't listed.
Probably an easy question, but I haven't find an answer covering so apologies if cross-posting.

Comment: Unless you have a domain / dyndns pointing to it, I'm afraid you can't without guessing/brute force. Do you have access to the DHCP server?

Comment: I can't login within it I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

The two comments by AdminBee and Panki nail it in my opinion: You need a mechanism that maps a dynamic IP to something static. This mechanism is normally DDNS, or perhaps mDNS if client and server are on the same network (on Linux, usually implemented by Avahi).

If you have access to the DHCP server, you could find the address in its logs or lease file.

Generally, I think that a machine should not have a dynamic IP address if it is used as a server.